# How to install git SSH keys in a docker container to access gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile

This is my use-case. I have a node application with a lot of dependencies. One of the dependency is from another git repo. When I try to build the container it fails for obvious reasons since it does not have ssh keys to access the repository. What is the best way to pull the repository and build the docker container ?

Answer (score 1):

Method #1: Put username/password in the repository URL:

```
git clone https://username:password@example.com/username/repository.git
```

Method #2: Copy the SSH key and related config file in Dockerfile:

```
# In Dockerfile
COPY sshkey /root/.ssh/sshkey
COPY sshconfig /root/.ssh/sshconfig
```

Method #3: Bind-mount the SSH key and related config file when running the container:

```
docker run -v sshkey:/root/.ssh/sshkey -v sshconfig:/root/.ssh/sshconfig ...
```

Be careful of any potential security risks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a volume to "copy" the ssh keys to the place where node will look for them during the build process within the container.